# VMWare ESXi confusion on needing patch

Tags: vmware-esxi

I checked the VMWAre Compatability Guide and have a bit of confusion regarding what it states.

The machine in question is an HP ProLiant DL380 G7 which it lists ESXi 4.1 Installable as compatible, with a caveat. The caveat states...

> This server uses a processor series
>   that requires a 4.0 U1 patch (Release
>   Name - ESX400-201002001, Bulletin ID
>   ESX400-201002401-BG / Release Name
>   ESXi400-201002001, Bulletin ID
>   ESXi400-201002401-BG) or newer for
>   full support.

I located the [patch](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018403)...however it appears this is all geared for 4.0 not, 4.1. In addition if I go download ESXi right now would this not be bundled as part of the download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with v4.1, as that falls under the "or newer" clause in the text you quoted.

Comment: ErikA On the compatibility guide why even place the reference to the caveat though, as it is hanging off a 4.1 reference to begin with, not a 4.0...? So there is no possible way to ever end up with 4.1 and needing that patch. Bad docs?

Comment: Yes, I would guess that it was indeed a case of bad documentation on HP's part.

Comment: @Aaron because someone simply amended an already existing document slightly when VMWare released 4.1 instead of reading through it carefully and tidying up things like that.